# B​ee​p-b​oo​p!​ What's my animal?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your friend who works at a telemarketing company loves leaving little codes for you all over the place! Today, she left an especially confusing piece of paper taped to your desk!

> `1209-852 1209-770 | 1477-770 1477-852 | 1477-770 1209-852 | 1477-770 1336-770 | 1209-852 1336-697` What's my favorite animal?

So? What's her favorite animal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Her favourite animal is a

> **TIGER**!

---

This was a different one! I hadn't seen this type of cipher before, the first cipher is

> [DTMF code](https://www.dcode.fr/dtmf-code), where the following table is used to decode the cipher:
>
>  [image]
>
> DTMF stands for Dual Tone Multi Frequency which are the frequencies of the 'beep' emitted for different characters on a telephone keypad
>
> Both the title and the telemarketing company hint at this (I somehow completely missed this lol)

Decoding gives

> **74 | 69 | 67 | 65 | 72**

Which is

> Hexadecimal for **TIGER**

Comment: WOW! Incredible job! Did you catch on to the hints I gave in the title and question?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I actually didn't, but I'll add that in now :P

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath oh wow how did I miss the title too :P