# Not quite binary

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your friend, the Kentucky telemarketer from [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101080/beep-boop-whats-my-animal), wants to meet you for a cool field trip! She could have just told you where to go... but that would be too easy, right? Instead, she left you a little note:

> `1001000 1011010 1010001 1011001 1010111 1001110 1010001 1001011 1011101 1001111 1011011` Be there at 7!
>
> Hint: I'm ???? da ba dee da ba daa

Hint 1:

> The `????` is not referring to blue... It's referring to another color! :):)
>
> Look into the connection of Kentucky with the above hint and maybe you'll find something interesting!

Hint 2:

> The color you are looking for from hint 1 is not black... it's not white, either.

Comment: I have a hint queued up for tomorrow if nobody's gotten it by then... :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now definitely got at least part of the answer (or perhaps the whole answer if I was over-thinking it?)

The decoded message is

> planetarium
>  Be there at 7!

To get there... a simple decoding as ASCII reveals

> nothing meaningful. "HZQYWNQK]O["

However, there's another kind of

> binary code referred to as a "[gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)", where only 1 bit changes between each consecutive number.
>  Rather than 0000->0001->0010->0011->0100->0101->0110->0111->1000 -> etc.
>  Instead use 0000->0001->0011->0010->0110->0111->0101->0100->1100 -> etc.
>  In each case the only bit that changes when counting in the Gray code is the same as the highest bit that changes in a normal binary number.

Using this,

> (or "[cheating](https://ncalculators.com/digital-computation/binary-gray-code-converter.htm)") we can convert to a standard binary code
>  1110000  1101100 1100001 1101110 1100101 1110100 1100001 1110010 1101001 1110101 1101101
>  which can then be interpreted as ASCII, yielding the word "planetarium"

It is not clear to me at this time

> Which specific planetarium is intended, as there seem to be several in Kentucky https://www.go-astronomy.com/planetariums-state.php?State=KY
>  and none of these are near to

a location I'd identified from earlier clues

> combining [Eiffel 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_65) (the band who wrote the words to the hint song) with Kentucky, to get Paris, KY, which has [**an** eiffel tower](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@38.2098977,-84.2529753,3a,75y,53.33h,89.75t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sk6kyP4Ancj1OSD07PkuInQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192) (quite a small one indeed).

but another more obvious location is available,

> Gray, KY

which is

> [just over an hour's drive](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Gray,+Kentucky+40734,+USA/%27%27/@37.3390522,-84.4286407,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x885cc67a83105f53:0x2ac26c4a995b91e2!2m2!1d-84.008263!2d36.9425894!1m5!1m1!1s0x8842fdb6d6654123:0x9bb1af9e1bd05757!2m2!1d-84.3037679!2d37.7304626) from [Hummel Planetarium](https://planetarium.eku.edu/)

a "field trip" can (normally) be arranged

> https://planetarium.eku.edu/field-trip-group-visit-information but I see nothing to suggest it's re-opened yet following the "temporary closure"?

Comment: Not bluegrass, exactly. The hints are a little more obscure than that! :):)

Comment: Maybe see if hint 1 helps at all?

Comment: The Kentucky hint was because there's a [town called Gray](http://www.city-data.com/city/Gray-Kentucky.html?scrlybrkr=a2d23c89#b) in Kentucky... :):) Nice job!